# Send message to Azure edgeHub from external client

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-iot-edge

We are using the Azure IoT Edge Runtime. So far we have created edge modules that read data from external sources and publish to the edgeHub but now we have a source data system that has no callable api but it can send data. I.e. the publisher system would like to do an http call or similar to the edgeHub with it's information.

The Azure Event Hub supports [http calls to send messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event) but is there any documentation on how send messages to the $edgeHub from external publishers?

Answer (score 2):

The Edge Hub does support HTTPS calls, the process is almost the same as IoT Hub's HTTPS support. The usual scenario in which this is used is when you configure Azure IoT Edge as a [transparent gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2020-11). If you follow the docs you end up with a configuration that will forward your publisher's messages directly to IoT Hub.

If your publisher system doesn't support this connection to Edge Hub, you could write a custom module that accepts HTTP messages.